# Implementing a copy on write String class using reference counting in C++

Tags: c++, object-oriented, strings, memory-management, proxy

I have tried to implement a copy on write string class with value semantics and reference counting.

I wanted to support indexing, so I have overloaded the operator[] and to differentiate between the l-value and r-value usage it is returning a proxy object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
class proxy;

//Reference counting class.Also holds the string.
class RC
{
    public:
        RC(const char * str);
        ~RC();
    private:
        char* str;
        int count;

    friend class mystring;
    friend class proxy;

};


class mystring
{
    public:
        mystring(const char*  str);
        mystring& operator=(const mystring& str);
        mystring(const mystring& str);
        ~mystring();

        void print() const;
        proxy operator[](int n);

    private:
        RC *pRC;

    friend class proxy;
};
class proxy
{
    public:
        proxy(mystring* r,int n);
        proxy& operator=(const char& c);
        proxy& operator=(const proxy& c);
        operator char() const;

    private:
        int n;
        mystring* ptr;
};


RC::RC(const char * str1)
:str(new char[strlen(str1)+1]),count(1)
{ 
    strcpy(str,str1);
}

RC::~RC()
{
    if(--count == 0)
        delete [] str;
}

proxy mystring::operator[](int n)
{
    return proxy(this,n);
}

mystring::mystring(const char*  str)
:pRC(new RC(str))
{
}
mystring& mystring::operator=(const mystring& rhs)
{
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
        if(--pRC->count == 0)
            delete pRC;
        pRC = rhs.pRC;
        ++pRC->count;
    }
    return *this;
}
mystring::mystring(const mystring& rhs)
{
    pRC = rhs.pRC;
    ++pRC->count;
}

mystring::~mystring()
{
    if(--pRC->count == 0)
        delete pRC;
}
void mystring::print() const
{
    std::cout << pRC->str << ":" << pRC->count << '\n';
}


proxy::operator char() const
{
    return ptr->pRC->str[n];
}

proxy::proxy(mystring* r,int n) 
:ptr(r),n(n)
{}

proxy& proxy::operator=(const char& c)
{

    if(c != ptr->pRC->str[n])
    {
        char cpy[strlen(ptr->pRC->str)+1];
        strcpy(cpy,ptr->pRC->str);
        ptr->pRC->~RC();
        cpy[n] = c;
        ptr->pRC = new RC(cpy);
    }

    return *this;
}


proxy& proxy::operator=(const proxy& rhs)
{
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
        *this = (char)rhs;

    }   

    return *this;
}
```

Can you please help me improve the code?

Answer (score 2):

### Code simplification

`mystring` acts essentially as a smart pointer. It's already implemented in the standard library. You can use the `std::shared_ptr` class. This way, `mystring` can just have an `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` as a member. The default copy constructor, assignment operator and the desturctor will work properly.

### Use of non-standard features

`char cpy[strlen(ptr->pRC->str)+1]`

variable sized arrays are not a part of the standard C++. Don't use them. If you need it, you should allocate it dynamically.

If you use the `std::shared_ptr<std::string>` as I said above, it'll be even simpler as `std::string` has a proper copy constructor.

### Index

It's conventional to use `size_t`, not `int` as an index type (at least that's how an `std::string` works).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions:

**Make `RC` a private, nested class**

`RC` is an implementation detail of `mystring`. It's best to make it a private, nested class.

**`RC` does not follow the rule of three**

`RC` allocates memory in its constructor and deallocates the memory in the destructor. All such classes should follow [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

You can get away with disregarding the rule of three if `RC` is a private, nested class. Even then, there is a possibility that you will run into problems if the implementations of any of the member functions of `mystring` is not mindful of that fact.

**Provide `operator[]` function in `RC`**

You had to make `proxy` a `friend` of `RC` in order to be able to access `strc`. Had you provided an `operator[]` function, that would have been necessary. Given the choices, I would recommend providing `operator[]` function(s) in `RC`.

**Fix the memory leak in `RC`**

You have:

```
RC::~RC()
{
   if(--count == 0)
      delete [] str;
}
```

However, the destructor of `RC` is called only when `count` is equal to `0` in couple of places.

In `mystring::operator=(const mystring& rhs)`:

```
  if(--pRC->count == 0)
     delete pRC;
```

In `mystring::~mystring`:

```
  if(--pRC->count == 0)
     delete pRC;
```

That means, you need to change the destructor of `RC` to be:

```
RC::~RC()
{
   // No need for this. count is already 0
   // if(--count == 0)
      delete [] str;
}
```

**Use a less cryptic name instead of `RC`**

Examples:

1. `mystring::ReferenceCountedData`
2. `mystring::Data`
3. `mystring:Implementation`

I would go with `mystring::Data`. The fact that it is reference counted is evident from the goal of `mystring`.

**Provide a `const` version of the `operator[]` function**

The current version of `operator[]` is a non-`const` function. If a function has a `const` object of type `mystring`, it won't be able to use the `operator[]` function get access the contents of the object. You should provide a `const` version of the `operator[]` function.

```
char operator[](size_t index) const
{
   return pRC->str[index];
}
```

If you would like to use a `proxy` for that function as well, you will need to use another class called `const_proxy`. That is analogous to the use of `iterator` and `const_iterator` in the container classes in the standard library.

```
const_proxy operator[](size_t index) const
{
   return const_proxy(this, index);
}
```

I'll leave the implementation of `const_proxy` as a detail.

**Avoid `mystring::print`**

I would recommend using an overload of `operator<<`. That makes `mystring` usable with all kinds of `ostream` objects. It also makes the task of outputting objects of the class more idiomatic.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, mystring const& s)
{
   return (out << pRC->str << ":" << pRC->count);
}
```

Now, you can use:

```
mystring obj("My Test String");
std::cout << obj << std::endl;
```